# KTOR - Compress Large json string in GET routing request

Tags: compression, ktor

New to this. Please provide block of code that can help me to compress large json to small size that can be faster to access with GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Compression](https://ktor.io/docs/compression.html) plugin to compress a response body using some algorithm like gzip.